# other way for reflashing ARDUINO YUN

Tags: arduino, reset, wireless, ethernet, firmware

so here is the problem

i have arduino yun [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCIwS.jpg) but, the Ethernet and Wireless AP is dead, my senior say that this arduino yun firmware experimented by unknown people, so i'm trying to surf the web and found out how to flash but they said it need to connected via Ethernet which you know that thing is dead.

I've tried via SDCard but doesn't seem to work, i didn't know the indicator if yun booting up or not (i want to know about this too).

If someone know how to flash beside using Ethernet or SDCard would be much appreciated because i truly needed it for socket programming and of course the price is high if i buy it again.

uhoh i forgot, here is the guy [our yun](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hDGEMhxeAczxfMdQMo5wMNxi-E6XdnwbKQ/view?usp=sharing)

What i have tried :

1. Reset button (Wireless) WLAN RST (if you asked how long i pressed it, i will say "you don't say, i tried all methods")
2. Reset button (Ethernet) 32U4 RST (how long ?| how many ?| "you don't say, i tried all methods")
3. Reset button YUN RST (how long ?| how many ?| ....... )
4. I think all the method above is bricking it's own firmware (am i wrong? lol)
5. i give up so i just wait for miracle to happens
6. oh yeah all the method above is not for reflashing does it? (lol)

What i haven't tried :

1. via MicroUSB (is it possible?)
2. via USB (flashdisk maybe?)
3. via Pin Port
4. via ICMP (what is this for anyway?!)
5. get that miracle to happens

that's it! any answer would be appreciated.

Thanks btw! Good day.

Answer (score 0):

If the ports your reference are truly dead, I would be suspicious of a system failure in which case the board is bricked. Even if you get it reflashed OK, those dead ports may wedge your firmware.

Comment: soooo, throw it to the trash can is the solution ??

Answer (score 0):

In windows, You can access your arduino yun via putty . Select select the serial connection mode with the COM port detected by your Arduino Ide